# How to assert that character occurs only once

Tags: regex

How to write a regex which matches `$Hi!$` but doesn't match `$$Hi!$$`? Currently I have `\$(.+)\$` but it still matches `$$Hi!$$`

Comment: Something like `(?<!\$)\$([^$]+)(?!\$)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  You should write an answer explaining look arounds.  I think it would be useful for people who have never seen them.

Comment: Should it include the last $ sign `(?<!\$)\$([^$]+)\$(?!\$)`

Comment: But I do not know if that is working for OP, there is too little information in the question.

Answer (score -1):

`\$([^\$]+)\$` will match anything that isn't a `$` and one `$` on each end